# SQL randomize results after previous result

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to randomize my final result in a query is it possible?

Here is my code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,updated,address,age
FROM people
ORDER BY updated DESC
LIMIT 0,50"`
```

At the end of this result could I have the 50 people returned Randomly with `UNION` maybe?

**UPDATE
A quick fix for me was to randomize the QUERY in PHP by using this method:
http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/randomize-sql-query-results.htm

Answer (score 3):

Use a subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT name,updated,address,age FROM people ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 0,50
) t ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: This did the trick but it does take well over 5 seconds complete. Is there a faster way?

Comment: @Zakukashi How long does your initial query take?

Comment: Thanks again, but I found a quick fix with PHP. I included the details in my main post.

Comment: You should add an index on the people table like so: ALTER TABLE people ADD INDEX `updated` (`updated`, `name`, `address`, `age);

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for me was to randomize the QUERY in PHP by using this method:
http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/randomize-sql-query-results.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should randomize the RESULTS in your php by using the function `shuffle()`